# Display resolution and scaling

Tags: display, resolution, scaling

I have a 27" monitor with 3840x2160 resolution.

I use 150 % scaling, does my monitor fit the same amount of information as a 2560x1440 monitor?

I consider getting ultrawide so I can keep two windows side-by-side with a decent width.

Either 34-35" 3440x1440 or 38" 3840x1600.

- Is it common to use 100 % scaling on those?
- Will they fit more information in width and height (or the same in height as 1440) than my current monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use 150 % scaling, does my monitor show 2560x1440 pixels?

No, it still uses all 3840x2160 pixels, it can't divide pixels according to your settings. It just scales up everything.

> Is it common to use 100 % scaling on those?

It's a very subjective question, depends on a lot of factor (content, watching distance...). The relative resolution (pixels per square inch / DPI) of your current monitor is much better compared to the new ones, it's likely you'll be able to notice that difference at whatever resolution you use.

> Will they fit more in width and height (or the same in height for the 1440p) as my current monitor?

I'm afraid I don't understand your question here. Fit to what? 1440p vertically? If you choose a monitor with 1440 pixels vertically, that's exactly 1440p

Comment: If I have open a document with text, can a 1440p monitor at 100 % scaling show the same amount of lines as my current monitor?

Comment: Yes. It'll be same height